# Verifying JWS with detached payload using jose4j fails

Tags: java, jwt, jose4j

I'm having issues verifying a JWS with detached payload. I've basically copied all steps in the [example provided](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/JWS%20Examples) on the jose4j documentation but for some reason verification still returns false while it should succeed.

Here's the code I'm using, using latest version of jose4j.

```
// signature is the complete JWS in the form: "JOSE Header".."JWS Signature"
// payload is the unencoded JSON string that makes up the request body
public boolean verifySignature(String signature, String payload) {

        JsonWebSignature jws = new JsonWebSignature();
        jws.setKnownCriticalHeaders(critHeaders); //critical headers from documentation
        //Algorithm as provided in documentation
        jws.setAlgorithmConstraints(new AlgorithmConstraints(AlgorithmConstraints.ConstraintType.PERMIT, 
                                                            AlgorithmIdentifiers.ECDSA_USING_P256_CURVE_AND_SHA256));
        jws.setPayload(payload);
        try {
            jws.setCompactSerialization(signature);
            String keyId = jws.getKeyIdHeaderValue();
            String keyType = jws.getKeyType();
            String keyAlg = jws.getAlgorithmHeaderValue();
            //Retrieve key from cached jwks
            JsonWebKey usedKey = jwks.findJsonWebKey(keyId, keyType, "sig", keyAlg);
            jws.setKey(usedKey.getKey());
            return jws.verifySignature();
        } catch  (JoseException e) {
            //log
            return false;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: *for some reason verification still returns false* - you should at least log the exception and tell us the result. And can you please add a link to the example to which you refer? That would be helpful as well.

Comment: @jps there is no exception, the `jws.verifySignature();` is returning the boolean value false, while it should be true. I've added the link to the example in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brian Campbell looked into this over on the jose4j Bitbucket, and this is his solution

> adding a jws.setEncodedPayload(null); right after jws.setCompactSerialization(signature); will make it work.

Apparently there is some inconsistency in my use case between the encoded/unencoded payload

Answer (score 2):

Try moving `jws.setPayload(payload);` down to after the `jws.setCompactSerialization(...);` line.
I *think* that `jws.setCompactSerialization(...);` is overwriting the payload to be the empty string, which would break the signature verification.

Comment: unfortunately this was not the solution

Comment: As an fyi, your hunch was correct in that setting the payload before the compact serialization was resetting the payloadBytes to an empty array

Comment: I couldn't get this working and had to switch over to Nimbus JOSE, so if you want I can open an issue over on bitbucket so you can investigate?

Comment: Sure, if you can provide enough info to look into it. Like the snippet of code used, the JWS, the payload, the public key / JWK, etc. And the snippet of Nimbus code that worked.

Comment: Done, good luck debugging!